# How to prevent docopt from swallowing an option?

Tags: python, command-line, docopt

I'm trying to create a command-line interface using docopt. Here is a simplified version of my file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Test program.

Usage:
  test.py [options]

Options:
  -a <input>    
  -b
  -c
  -d
"""
import docopt

print docopt.docopt(__doc__)
```

I essentially want to be able to specify any of the options, in any order. However, if I forget to specify the argument for the `-a` flag, then I get an output like this:

```
$ python test.py -a -b -c
{"-a": "-b",
 "-b": False,
 "-c": True,
 "-d": False}
```

Docopt is treating the `-b` flag as the argument for the `-a` flag, instead of rejecting the input as invalid. Is there some easy way to detect this, or make docopt refuse to accept this sort of malformed input?

Answer (score 2):

There are some ambiguities concerning the short option : better use the --option=ARG long option :

> ### -o --option
>
> Words starting with one or two dashes (with exception of "-", "--" by
>   themselves) are interpreted as short (one-letter) or long options,
>   respectively.
>
> ```
> - Short options can be "stacked" meaning that -abc is equivalent to -a -b -c.
> - Long options can have arguments specified after space or equal "=" sign: --input=ARG is equivalent to --input ARG.
> -Short options can have arguments specified after optional space: -f FILE is equivalent to -fFILE.
> ```
>
> Note, writing --input ARG (opposed to --input=ARG) is ambiguous,
>   meaning it is not possibe to tell whether ARG is option's argument or
>   positional argument. In usage patterns this will be interpreted as
>   option with argument only if option's description (covered below) for
>   that option is provided. Otherwise it will be interpreted as separate
>   option and positional argument.
>
> Same ambiguity is with -f FILE and -fFILE notation. Although in the
>   latter case it is not possible to tell whether it is a number of
>   stacked short options, or an option with argument. These notations
>   will be interpreted as option with argument only if option's
>   description is provided.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically a design decision right now, that option's argument could be an arbitrary string. We are discussing whether it is a good decision or not.